Finding tangent lines that go through the origin
At what points on the curve, $y = 2x^3 + 12x^2 + 5x + 9$ does its
tangent line pass through the origin?
Note: The book's answer is:
$$ x= -3,-1, \dfrac{3}{4} $$
Answer:
The set of points we are looking for include all points $(x,y)$ such that $x > 0$ and $f'(x) = y$. The set of points we are looking for also includes the point $(0, f(0))$
if $f(0) = 0$. In this case, $f(0) \neq 0$.  The set of points we are looking for also includes they point $(x,f(x))$ such that $x < 0$ and $-x = f'(x)$.
$$ f'(x) = 6x^2 + 24x + 5 $$
Now we consider the  case where $x > 0$.
\begin{align*}
6x^2 + 24x + 5 &= 2x^3 + 12x^2 + 5x + 9 \\
6x^2 + 24x  &= 2x^3 + 12x^2 + 5x + 4 \\
2x^3 + 6x^2 - 19x + 4 &= 0 \\
\end{align*}
Now to solve this equation, we apply the rational root theorem. Using this theorem,
I realize that $\dfrac{3}{4}$ cannot be a solution.
I want to look at the point where $x = \dfrac{3}{4}$.
\begin{align*}
f\left( \dfrac{3}{4}  \right) &=
 2\left( \dfrac{3}{4} \right) ^3 + 12 \left( \dfrac{3}{4} \right) ^2
 + 5 \left( \dfrac{3}{4} \right) + 9 \\
%
f\left( \dfrac{3}{4}  \right) &=
 \dfrac{ 2(27) }{64} + \dfrac{ 12(9) }{16}+ \dfrac{15}{4} + 9 \\
%
f\left( \dfrac{3}{4}  \right) &=
 \dfrac{ 27 }{32} + \dfrac{ 6(9) }{8}+ \dfrac{15}{4} + \dfrac{ 9(32) }{32} \\
%
f\left( \dfrac{3}{4}  \right) &= \dfrac{ 27 + 54(4) + 15(8) + 9(32)  }{32} \\
f\left( \dfrac{3}{4}  \right) &= \dfrac{ 651  }{32} \\
\end{align*}
Now, I want to compuate $f'\left(  \dfrac{3}{4} \right)  $.
\begin{align*}
f'\left(  \dfrac{3}{4} \right)  &=
 6 \left( \dfrac{3}{4}\right) ^2 + 24\left( \dfrac{3}{4}  \right) + 5 \\
%
f'\left(  \dfrac{3}{4} \right)  &= \dfrac{6(9)}{16}+ \dfrac{12(3)}{2} + 5 \\
f'\left(  \dfrac{3}{4} \right)  &= \dfrac{27}{8}+ 18 + 5 \\
f'\left(  \dfrac{3}{4} \right)  &= \dfrac{27}{8} + 23 = \dfrac{ 27 + 8(23)}{8}\\
f'\left(  \dfrac{3}{4} \right)  &= \dfrac{ 211 }{8}
\end{align*}
Where did I go wrong? Is the book wrong?

the book is wrong

I now believe I copied the problem wrong.

This is a typo in the book.
The exercise works well for $y = 2x^3 + {\color{blue}{13}}x^2 + 5x + 9$.
You can easily verify this by calculating the polynomial belonging to the given roots and removing the fractions:
$$4(x+3)(x+1)\left(x-\frac 34 \right) = 2x^3 + {\color{blue}{13}}x^2 + 5x + 9$$

+1 : This is nice reverse engineering.
